# Clear values from Netsuite Item Custom field

Tags: netsuite

I have created a Custom Field in Netsuite for Item.
Due to some data issue, the value in the custom field is corrupted and i need to again reset all the values to null or empty.

How i can empty the Custom Field value to null through the Netsuite Portal and not through scripts?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the data type on the custom field.  You will get a warning saying "Changing this custom field type will delete all data in existing records.  Are you sure you want to do this?" Click "OK" and save, then you can change it back to the original data type and carry on as you were.

Answer (score 4):

@Krypton's answer is definitely the fastest, you can also use the Mass Update feature to accomplish this, but you'll need to do each item type individually:

- `Lists -> Mass Update -> Mass Updates`
- Expand "General Updates"
- Click on `Items -> Inventory Item`
- Leave the "Criteria" blank if you want to clear the field for all records
- On the "Mass Update Fields" tab, check the "Apply" box next to the field you want to clear
- Do not enter anything in the "Value" column
- Click the "Preview" button.
- Click the "Perform Update" button

You'll need to do this for each item type (Inventory Item, Non-Inventory Item (for Sale), Kit/Package, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to uncheck the Store Value, save, check Store Value, save.